# Python Selenium create a method to get or hardcode?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to figure out best practices in Python Selenium.
I have my own implementation of the page object where I have a method to do the most basic action: get.

```
    def get(self, locator):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(((locator))))
        return element
```

Then I have classes with locators:

```
class MyClass(BasePage):
     def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        
        self.CONTACT_FORM_FLOATER_LOC = (By.ID, 'block_inside_floater')
        self.NAVBAR_LOGIN_BTN_LOC = (By.ID, 'desktop_main_menu_login')
```

So now i can easily do:

```
my_class = MyClass(driver)
login_btn = my_class.get(my_class.NAVBAR_LOGIN_BTN_LOC)
```

However I have seen many tutorials implementing methods to get elements with using this approach:

```
class MyClass(BasePage):
     def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def get_login_btn(self, locator)
        element = self.get(locator)
        return element
```

And then do:

```
my_class = MyClass(driver)
login_btn = my_class.get_login_btn(my_class.NAVBAR_LOGIN_BTN_LOC)
```

This might sound silly but is there a general standard practice to choose which approach to take?

Comment: Seems to call for an opinion, so I'll give mine... "best practices" are for people who want to get something up and running quickly without completely understanding what they are doing.  You are obviously figuring things out for yourself, which is a better way of learning/grokking.  Page Object Model is not really a strict guideline... it's goal is to make re-usable components and there are many approaches to that depending on your requirements.

Comment: thank you @pcalkins, I will make my own best practices then :)